# How to debug the SqlLite database used in Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I was searching for some trick to debug the database of an Android app in Ionic on a phone and I've encountered this [project](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database).
How can I use this with Ionic? If there is no way, can I use others tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are executing on a device and need to view the data stored by sqlite, install the "[stetho](https://github.com/OutSystems/cordova-plugin-stetho-android)" plugin, it lets you open a dev tool with sqlite data. connect the device on the computer, open the app, open the chrome and type in the navigation bar "chrome://inspect", and click the link related to "stetho".

Also don’t forget to reboot.