# Ionic+Cordova : how to preview android local SQLite database from chrome browser?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, google-chrome, ionic-framework

Im trying to make hybrid android application + SQLite database using ionic(Angular4)+cordova, so sometimes i need to browse my SQLite database.

i know that there is a android applications to do that, but i want to manage this database from my chrome browser.

is there any way to preview and manage this local SQLite database from chrome browser ?

Comment: Preview yes, manage no.  To preview click inspect -> Application tab.  There should be a section called storage where you can view all sorts of local storage.

Comment: I already answered here-https://stackoverflow.com/q/51349621/1081909

Comment: You can use websql when you are running in browser and use sqlite when you are in mobile just db creation syntax have changes other all things are same so you can like this